# jQuery how to add class to a parent div which has a 3rd level child div with a specific class name

Tags: php, jquery, class, append

Hello friends I have an issue adding a special class to a couple of my divs. My layout is like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid-6 push-3 equal" style="height: 999px;">
        <div class="block">
            <div id="mainbody"> 
                <!-- Body content here --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-2 equal" style="height: 999px;">
        <div class="block">
            <div id="sidebar-a"> 
                <!-- Sidebar-a content here --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-2 equal" style="height: 999px;">
        <div class="block">
            <div id="sidebar-b"> 
                <!-- Sidebar-b content here --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-2 equal" style="height: 999px;">
        <div class="block">
            <div id="sidebar-c"> 
                <!-- Sidebar-c content here --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a different background color to each of my sidebars via CSS and when I code like:

```
#mainbody { background : #fff; }
#sidebar-a { background : #eee; }
#sidebar-b { background : #ddd; }
#sidebar-c { background : #ccc; }
```

It is applying the background only to that specific class but that specific class is not of equal height. I actually need to apply to this `<div class="grid-2 equal" style="height: 999px;">` div.

Now the issue is that in this

`<div class="grid-6 push-3 equal" style="height: 999px;">` and `<div class="grid-2 equal" style="height: 999px;">`

the class names `grid-6` and `grid-2` are generated dynamically by my PHP of 960 Grid System and also the `style="height: 999px;` is generated by a jQuery script for Equal-Columns.

What I want is to add a unique class name like this...... Look for a `div` with a `class` of `.equal` which has a `child div` with a `class` of `.block` and which further has a `child div` with an `ID` of `sidebar-a`.

IF TRUE then add a `class` of `.sidebar-a` to the main`div` which has a `class` of `.equal`

So that the result looks like this:

```
<div class="grid-6 equal push-3 mainbody" style="height: 999px;">
<div class="grid-2 equal sidebar-a" style="height: 999px;">
<div class="grid-2 equal sidebar-b" style="height: 999px;">
<div class="grid-2 equal sidebar-c" style="height: 999px;">
```

Then I'll be able to style it like this:

```
.mainbody { background : #fff; }
.sidebar-a { background : #eee; }
.sidebar-b { background : #ddd; }
.sidebar-c { background : #ccc; }
```

Hence I thought since I am anyway using jQuery in my Template, why not use it to deal with this issue. Please feel free to suggest a better way if you have something else in mind.

Comment: Classic mistake Number One:  Duplicate ID attributes.  Your document is invalid, and JavaScript will act funny and/or fail until you fix that problem...   unless that was just a typo!  (sidebar-b is listed twice)

Comment: Oh yes that was a typo. Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform you selection logic in a standard jQuery selector, and then for each sidebar you find travel up the DOM tree finding the first div with the class `equal` and attaching a class to it with the name of each sidebar's id:

```
$('div.equal div.block div[id^="sidebar"]').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.equal').addClass(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Definitely the way to do this. +1 if I hadn't run out of votes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the code but nop didn't work. I used like this.....  $(document).ready(function() {
   
   $('div.equal div.block div[id^="sidebar"]').each(function() {
   $(this).closest('equal').addClass(this.id);
   });

  }); Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry but am a newbie when it comes to programming. I have just started learning. Kindly help.

Comment: Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/EWxss/) which shows it working, it alerts out the class names for every element `div.equal` after executing the code in my answer. You will see that the classes `sidebar-a` etc. are in there.

Comment: @Vikram: You have `.closest('equal')`. You need `.closest('.equal')` (notice the `.` before `equal`, as it denotes a class name). Or do as in the example @Marcus gave: `.closest('div.equal')`

Comment: Finally.... Yes it works. Thanks Thanks Thanks and Thanks a lot Marcus. That was great.